# Ubuntu won't shutdown in a timely manner

Tags: 16.04

I have a dual boot system with windows 10 along with Ubuntu 16.04.
The startup time is quite good for Ubuntu. However, it takes too much time to shutdown. Eventually, I have to disconnect the power source to power off.

I run `Hadoop` in my system. Is this is because of this, or maybe something else is the cause of this?

Comment: Can you switch to `tty1` and run `sudo shutdown -h now` and see if there are any messages saying things such as it's waiting for one minute and then it will send a `SIGTERM` to a specific process?